# Spring boot - Externalized JNDI Configuration

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

The [SpringBoot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) mention a way to externalize configuration through JNDI (java:comp/env).

So, the question is: how can we configure an application server such as Tomcat to reference a property file (like application.properties)? Is there a sample somewhere? Some explanations, etc? A bunch of posts are related to the datasource configuration through JNDI but nothing about the application configuration.

Comment: Could you try to explain a bit better what you try to do exactly? *"Appserver referencing a property file"* is not that clear.

Comment: Suppose an application deployed on an Application Server like Tomcat. The idea would be to override some configurations entries defined in application.properties. Ideally, I would like to define a new property file somewhere outside my web app. Then, through JNDI, I would like to use this file to override the defaults. I hope this explanation is more clear than the previous one.